# Evaluating a triangle at a specific (x,y) coordinate

Tags: c, math, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

Given: The 3 triangle vertices in a 3D space, the x,y coordinates of a point on that triangle(triangle area included).

Wanted: The z coordinate of the given point.

All 3 triangle vertices have different (x,y) coordinates(they're heightmap coordinates), so the case of multiple(infinite) matches doesn't need to be handled.

I'm trying to do this in C, meaning an algorithm operating on simple number types e.g. floats would be best(no matrix or vector operations).

Comment: So [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What is your specific question?

Comment: For a start if dealing with 3D you need the x, y and z coordinated of each of the three points. Just think of a map that is a flat. They add contours to add the extra dimension!

Comment: Just to be clear, is this what you are asking: find intersection between a plane in 3D space defined by 3 points, and a Z-axis-aligned line defined by it's X and Y coordinates?

Comment: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/MathGem:Height_of_a_Point_in_a_Triangle

Comment: @hyde: Yes, exactly. I thought of expressing it like that, but was unsure about the exact wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done typically with vectors / matrices, which are just shorter notations for the underlying operations.

- select a reference point from the three vertices O = (ox, oy) = Point1
- make two vectors U=(ux,uy) = point2 - O; V=(vx,vy) = point3 - O
- solve the linear system
  x,y = u*U + v*V   for u and v

  x = u * (p2x-ox) + v * (p3x-ox)
  y = u * (p2y-oy) + v * (p3y-oy)

Check that 0 <= u,v <= 1 and 0<=u+v<=1
If yes, then the point x,y is inside the triangle and
    z = u*(p2z-oz)+v*(p3z-oz)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this actually is all there is to this problem. I thought there was something involved like converting the vectors to an orthonormal base, but apparently there's no need to.